# Can I start a chatbot conversation in Dialogflow using external events?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'd like to make my bot initiate a conversation with the user based on external events. I read the documentation, but I'm still not sure if this is possible, I feel like the conversation only starts on behalf of the user. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, conversations must begin by the user invoking your bot.

However, you can use push notifications to encourage a user to engage with the bot. Also you can use a push notification to deep link into your bot and open a specific intent. You would have to write a script that depends on your external trigger to send a notification, and that would depend on your external trigger. You can read more about notifications for Google Assistant here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-user-engagement/